# Read file using kafka file connector in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have written a very simple code in Java to read a file and send those records to Kafka topic. Everything is working as expected. But, instead of writing file , I want to use Kafka file connector. I did it in the past using REST proxy(curl) command but never tried in java. I need some help to do it.

I can see there is Kafka-connect api in Maven repository and I can add it in my pom.xml file. What should be my next step to integrate it in my java code.

**My code to read file without Kafka connect** :

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleProducer_ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       // System.out.println("Hello Kafka ");

        // setting properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());

        // create the producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> produce = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);


        //reading file
        File read = new File("C:\\Users\\\Desktop\\TestFile.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(read);
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){

            String data = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(data);

            //create the producer record
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test-topic",data);

            //send data
            produce.send(record);
        }

        //flush and close
        produce.flush();
        produce.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) and [`FileStreamSource`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/filestream_connector.html#filesource-connector) connector that reads data from a file and sends it to Kafka.

---

In your case, the configuration should be

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/path/to/file.txt
topic=test-topic
```

---

Now the equivalent `curl` command would be:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"name": "local-file-source", "config": {"connector.class":"FileStreamSource", "tasks.max":"1", "file":"path/to/file.txt", "topics":"test-topic" }}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

If you want to do this programmatically, simply send a [`POST`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#post--connectors) request as above.